# No database selected error apperared

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

A sudden error appeared on my screen saying "No database Selected".
I read out all the solutions to solve it but did not find any solution helpful as i have tried all those solutions.
I have been working with the same connection.php file many times in previous projects.
Also, i have checked that all privileges are ok. 
Kindly Help me !

db_connection.php

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "m");
?>
```

data.php

```
<?php
include './includes/db_connection.php';

$check = "SELECT name FROM web_marketing";
$sth1 = mysql_query($check);
print_r($sth1);
 die($check."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
?>
```

Comment: use mysql_select_db to select database. Also mysql has been dapricated, use mysqli or pdo

Comment: @ChetanAmeta
Oh My goodness !
I forget to write mysqli_query() instead of mysql_query().
Just , this solved my problem !
Thanks dear !